# Why does value is never used?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have

```
<input
  v-model="totalAmount"
  @focus="hideSymbol(totalAmount)"
  @blur="showSymbol(totalAmount)"
/>
...
const totalAmount = ref('')
```

So I want to cahnge value on focus and blur

```
const hideSymbol = (val: string) => {
  val = val.slice(0, -1)
}

const showSymbol = (val: string) => {
  val = `${val} s`
}
```

So I get `The value assigned to 'val' is never used`
I think that I missed very important thing in learning so i can't resolve it. How can I get it? Help please!

I expected changed value in input

Comment: In each of your functions, line one takes the value you pass to the `val` variable as an argument, does *something* with it, then assigns the result to the `val` variable. Now the `val` variable has a *new value* and you get to the end of the function having done *nothing* with the new value. Hence the warning. What's the point of the functions? What do you *want* to do with the new value?

Comment: @Quentin, so I think that i can pass ref's name and change it's value by:
`const hideSymbol = (val: typeof totalAmount) => {
  val.value = val.value.slice(0, -2)
}`
But val.value is undefined

Comment: @stanislavkim val is not a ref in the template, it's unwrapped. You won't be able to do this the way you currently try. Either hardcode hideSymbol etc to use totalAmount, or use reactive object with totalAmount property, so you could pass property name to hideSymbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the value into the functions.

Just use a Vue data property like this:

```js
 const { ref, createApp } = Vue;
   
 const App = { 
    setup() {       
      const totalAmount = ref('')
      return {
        totalAmount
      }
   },
   methods: {
      hideSymbol() {
        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount.slice(0, -2);
      },
      showSymbol () {
        this.totalAmount = `${this.totalAmount} s`
      }
   }
}

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <input
      v-model="totalAmount"
      @focus="hideSymbol()"
      @blur="showSymbol()"
    />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"> 
</script>
```

Be sure you really want to have an 's' in your value when the form submit occurs.